# Push a variable into an array and update the array each time we click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am saving a variable into an array with a click on an item, but this should change each time I click on a different item. Currently this is alerting the same value and not the new one.

```
<div class="item">
     <span id="0" class="video" data-vimeoid="http://vimeo.com/XXX"></span>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <span id="1" class="video" data-vimeoid="http://vimeo.com/SSS"></span>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <span id="2" class="video" data-vimeoid="http://vimeo.com/ZZZ"></span>
</div>
```

Then in jQuery

```
var previous = [];
$(document).on( 'click', '.item:not(.is-expanded)', function() {
    var url = videoSpan.data("vimeoid");
    previous.push(url);
    alert(previous[0]);
});
```

Comment: pushing at end not change `0 th ` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do

```
var previous = [];
$(document).on( 'click', '.item:not(.is-expanded)', function() {
    var url = videoSpan.data("vimeoid");
    previous.push(url);
    alert(previous[previous.length-1]);
});
```

Comment: i thought .push() was replacing the value while .add() was adding

Comment: No `.push()` pushes a new element. If it solves your problem please consider voting it up and marking it as correct answer.

Comment: Nope push adds to the end of the array see docs for details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: @rob.m Try to learn to not use alert for debugging. If you did `console.log( previous )` you'd see the entire array in the browser console.

Comment: @void will do once i will be able to ;)